# TeamCity SQL Project : Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets was not found

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, teamcity, roundhouse

TeamCity

I have a TeamCity project with a `.NET CLI (dotnet) build step` for a `Visual Studio Solution ( .sln )`.

The solution includes a `SQL Project ( .sqlproj )`.

Running this build-step gives error :

```
[build] D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e9ff385151b10e4c\Services\AccountCharacteristics\Database-RoundHouse-Deploy1\Database\Database.sqlproj(67,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Database.sqlproj

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- Default to the v11.0 targets path if the targets file for the current VS version is not found -->
    <SSDTExists Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets')">True</SSDTExists>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' != ''" Project="$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' == ''" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
```

So it appears that `SQLDBExtensionsRefPath  = C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\`

Apparently the `.sqlproj` defaults to 11.0 -- a very old version of `Visual Studio`.

How does `SQLDBExtensionsRefPath` get set ?   How can I install/config the agent for the correct path ?

My agent has :

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets`

Also I notice that a NuGet package has been released :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild/

But it's not clear how to use it. It seems clear I need to reference the package in the `VS .csproj`. But then how to ensure that `Visual Studio` and `Team City` point to the `Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets` in the package ( under the `packages` folder ) ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  If so, you should answer your own question.  It would be very helpful.

Comment: any updates? I am currently working on the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set it as an environment variable with
setx SQLDBExtensionsRefPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\SSDT"

or by adding via the 'environment variables' in the Windows UI

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ssdt/part-5-use-your-own-build-and-deployment-agent